# Python SK-Learn KNN Imputer ( "ValueError: could not convert string to float: )

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, k-nn, data-imputation

I have data with missing values.
All columns are integer, except for a column that has missing values.
These missing values, were set with a "?" which was converted to NaN using the Numpy function.
This is the result of using df.info():

[image]

So only one column is an Object type, which makes sense, because that is where the NaN is.
When I try to use the KNN-imputer, it gives error :"ValueError: could not convert string to float: )

I got around this by converting the Pandas Dataframe to Numpy Array.
But how to I get around this if I just want to use the Pandas Array.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Could you provide  the full code that generate the error , including line where you did replace "?" with  NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing the `?` with `np.NaN`, you will be able to convert the type of the `BareNuc` column from `object` to `float` (as `np.NaN` is considered a special floating-point value and cannot be converted to any other type than `float`).
with that, you wouldn’t need to convert to a NumPy array.

```
df = df.astype({"BareNuc": float})
```

At the end, all columns will be used as `float` type, so that wouldn’t affect the resource allocation.

Comment: Hi El Houcine, thanks for your reply. It looks very good. I will give you this question! Thanks so much!